# WPF Form Validation

Tags: wpf, validation, begininvoke

```
private void StartDate_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!validate())
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
        DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle,
        new Action(delegate()
        {
            StartDate.Focus();
        })
     });
}
```

I'm validating a date in the lost focus of a textbox of a WPF application.  Currently, I do some date validation - if it fails validation I reset the focus to the textbox.  Is this the correct approach?

It seems to be working fine, I'm hoping I'm not creating any problems or memory leaks with the BeginInvoke.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This works, but doesn't make much sense to me. You are executing the actual validation in the UI thread synchronously (blocking the UI thread), and then you are moving focus to the StartDate control in BeginInvoke (still UI thread, but asynchronously). Are you sure this is what you're aiming for?

Comment: What I wanted to say is, since you're validating in the UI thread synchronously already, there's no point in executing the Focus() method asynchronously. Do it in the UI thread as well. What I would suggest is doing the validation asynchronously (UI or, preferably, in a different thread), and then set the focus synchronously in the UI thread.

Comment: I recommend having a look at [`IDataErrorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.aspx) and [`INotifyDataErrorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) for a more standard approach to validations in WPF.

Comment: @ Piotr Justyna, if I take out the delegate, the focus moves to the next textbox.  I want to return it to the same start date textbox, so the user can correct it.

Comment: @fjr_nj I see what you mean but in fact the system is behaving as it should. You are validating the content just after the focus is lost and nothing is stopping the application from moving the focus to the next textbox. I will post sample code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Adi suggested, please consider using more common approach to validation. However, if the application you're working on is something just for fun or just to get to know how WPF works, please consider:

1. validating asynchronously
2. interacting with UI synchronously in the UI thread

Also, validate before losing the focus (TextChanged might be an option). Something like this:

```
    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox validatedTextbox = sender as TextBox;
        validatedTextbox.IsEnabled = false;

        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

        worker.DoWork += (s, ea) => { Thread.Sleep(1000); }; // just to simulate really long validation
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, ea) =>
        {
            if (validatedTextbox.Text.Contains('a'))
            {
                validatedTextbox.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }
            else
            {
                validatedTextbox.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            }

            validatedTextbox.IsEnabled = true;
        };

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I chose the lostFocus over the textChange event because I thought this validation would fire on each key stroke...i.e., so for today - 0 validate() 6 validate() 2 validate()  8 validate() etc.  Are there any issues with that?

Comment: I don't think so, really. Well, the answer is very specific to the context of your validation, e.g. how it affects the user experience, so you have to answer it yourself. From the purely technical point of view, however, that's the way the validation should be working - validation behind the scenes and updating the UI afterwards in the UI thread. I believe that was your original question.